# Is there a possibility to get a list of all the available sizes of an uploader?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

Let's say I have an uploader for avatars with two sizes defined.

```
class AvatarUploader < ApplicationUploader
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  def default_url
    "/images/placeholder_#{version_name}.png"
  end

  process resize_to_fill: [200, 200]

  version :large_thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [78, 78]
  end

  version :small_thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [33, 33]
  end

  def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

Is there a way to get all the available size in an array or hash?

In the best case scenario - that some sort of method would return:

```
User.new.avatar.available_sizes = [:large_thumb, :small_thumb]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
User.new.avatar.versions.keys
```

`CarrierWave::Uploader#versions` returns a `Hash` with the version name as key and the corresponding URL as the value.